# Emacs hangs after describe-variable on package-archive-contents

Tags: package, help

When I try run `describe-variable` on `package-archive-contents` `C-h v package-archive-contents` emacs hangs. It hangs at least 5 minutes, maybe forever (I did not wait any longer).

Seems like `Esc : (print package-archive-contents)` also almost hangs.. It outputs an enormous string to message buffer after a minute. When trying to copy the string to the clipboard emacs hangs again..

I am running Emacs version 25.1 on Ubuntu 16.10.

Running `C-h v package-archives` gives current value:

```
 (("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/") ("marmalade"
 . "http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/") ("melpa"
 . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/") ("org"
 . "http://orgmode.org/elpa/"))
```

Comment: `package-archive-contents` contains meta-information about all versions of all packages in all archives.  That's a huge amount of data; printing all of it naturally takes quite some time.

Comment: @lunaryorn Agree. But I was only trying to get the documentation for the variable: `C-h v package-archive-contents`. It should not try to print the variable (if it is large) when a user tries to get the documentation

Comment: I see.  I guess you need to report that as a bug

Answer (score 3):

To debug Emacs, it's always best to start a new instance with the `-q` option.  This opens Emacs without loading an init file.  You can then start investigating with the `C-h v` and `C-h f` commands which open documentation for variables and functions, respectively.

It looks like `package-archive-contents` is not part of base Emacs, but rather `package.el`.  Execute `(require 'package)` to load it.  Once `package.el` has been loaded, the documentation for variable `package-archive-contents` reads as:

```
package-archive-contents is a variable defined in ‘package.el’.
Its value is nil.

  This variable may be risky if used as a file-local variable.

Documentation:
Cache of the contents of the Emacs Lisp Package Archive.
This is an alist mapping package names (symbols) to
non-empty lists of ‘package-desc’ structures.
```

The cache of the Emacs Lisp Package Archive may be quite large.  In the case of Emacs being opened with `-q`, only `elpa` will be cached.  To do this, run `(package-initialize)`.  Now the documentation for `package-archive-contents` will take longer to load.  It took several minutes for me. This is because the value is no longer `nil`.  The value is 1000+ lines of information.  Consider that in your case, you have the additional archives of `melpa` and `marmalade`.

Comment: It should be faster in Emacs 26, for earlier versions, indenting lisp was quadratic in the number of lines of the expression being indented (see [Bug#25122](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=25122)).